# Android: Gridview performance?

Tags: android, performance, gridview, bitmap

on my Activity i've got on each side (on the right/on the left) a constrain Layout (100dp width). Between those gridviews i have a Gridlayout. This grid i fill with the help of an adapter. Now it contains 32*52 squares which contain a black/white image. With buttons placed on the constrain layouts i change the colour of choosen squares. But if i try this on several devices, this way is not realy performant and quite laggy. Is der a better way to do this? How? I found something on Bitmaps and canverals.. would this be better? How should i use this? Can someone  recommend a tutorial? Or what other ways of achieving this exists?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As all we know, RecyclerView enhance flexibility and also improve smoothness. So you can use RecyclerView Or RecyclerView with CardView.

> And instead of using Bitmaps I would recommend you to use Glide
>   Library to Show Images
>
> You can use Glide library for display image.So just add it in
>   build.gradle(Module App)

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

to set Images

```
 Glide.with(context).load(image_path).into(imageView);
```

Note: image_path can be string, int resource, file or anything else bcoz Glide can load everything

Following are the tutorial links for RecyclerView with cardview:

link1:  http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

link2:  http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/